# Add Preloading image while loading <ons-tabbar> on Onsen UI with Phonegap?

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, cordova, onsen-ui

Right now I'm making an iPhone app with Onsen UI and Phonegap (Cordova).

When I open a new page from `<ons-tabbar>` it would have a little flash on the screen before the new page appeared.

So anyone know how to add a loading image before the new page appear to make it look smoother than before, or another solutions to make it look better?

This is some of my code:

```
<ons-tabbar class="tab-wrapper">
      <ons-tab class="first-footer-button" page="feeds-index.html" active="true">
        <!-- <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon> -->
        <img src="img/icon/feeds_icon.png" alt="">
        <span>Feeds</span>
      </ons-tab>
      <ons-tab page="recents-index.html">
        <!-- <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon> -->
        <img src="img/icon/recents_icon.png" alt="">
        <span>Recents</span>
      </ons-tab>
      <ons-tab page="settings.html">
        <!-- <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon> -->
        <img src="img/icon/profile_icon.png" alt="">
        <span>Profile</span>
      </ons-tab>
      <ons-tab page="settings.html">
        <!-- <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon> -->
        <img src="img/icon/history_icon.png" alt="">
        <span>History</span>
      </ons-tab>
      <ons-tab page="settings.html">
        <!-- <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon> -->
        <img src="img/icon/setting_icon.png" alt="">
        <span>Setting</span>
      </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ons-loading-placeholder` attribute has been added in Onsen UI 1.2.0.

It can be used as follows:

```
<div ons-loading-placeholder="page.html">
  Loading...
</div>
```

You can put some animation inside the `<div>`.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, maybe i put it in the wrong section.
So Where should i put this element.

Thank you so much!